# I have an error of undefined variable in my script

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a login and signup system using PHP and this is the error I am getting on the signup page when defining a variable for the user_id

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function random_num() in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\signup.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\signup.php on line 17

Here is my code for the signup.php

```
<?php
    //start of session
    session_start();
    
    //include files
    include("connection.php");
    include("functions.php");

    //need to check if the user has clicked on the post button 
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" ) {
        // It means that someone has already signed up so we need to username and password
        $username = $_POST['user_name'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        //we need to check if username and password are not empty also we can use different conditions for the username and password before savign them to database 
        if(!empty($username)&& !empty($password) && !is_numeric($username)){

            //If everthing is correct then we will add to the database 
            $user_id= random_num(20);

            $query = "insert into users (user_id,user_name,password) values ($user_id,$user_name,$password)";
            mysqli_query($query);
            
            //once everything is one lets redirect the user to the login page 
            header(Location:login.php);
            die;
        } else {
            echo "Please enter some valid information!";
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <style type="text/css">/*truncated*/</style> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
        <form method="post">
            <div style="font-size: 20px;margin: 10px;color: white;">Sign Up</div>
            <input id="text" type="text" name="user_name"><br><br>
            <input id="text" type="password" name="password"><br><br>
            <input id="button" type="submit" value="Signup"><br><br>
            <a href="login.php">Click to Login</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am also attaching the code for the function file I have made. I am learning PHP so need to identify where the problem is

```
<?php
// so what we are doing is chcecking if the session value exists then stay on the index page otherwise redirect to the login.php
//this fucntion will check if the user is logged in 
function check_login($con){

// first we will check the session value 
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        //LETS CHECK IN THE DATABASE
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '$id' LIMIT 1";
        
        //read from database
        $result = mysql_query($con, $query);
        
        //now check if the result is positive and the number of rows are greater than zero

        if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
            //assoc is the associtive array
            $user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            return $user_data;
        }
    }

    //redirect to login
    header("Location: login.php");
}

//function for the $user_id
function random_num($length){
    $text = "";
    // to make sure the lenght is never less than 5 
    if($length<5){
        $length=5;  
    }
    
    //assign a variable between 4, the number we have whihc is 20
    $len = ran(4,$length);
    for( $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){ 
        # code...
        $text.=rand(0,9);
    }
    
    return $text;
}
```

So it is showing me the error is in the login file in the line 17 which is the one in which I defined the `user_id=random_num(20);`

Also if you need to know more about my project attaching the code for the connection.php as well

```
<?php
    //connection to database 
    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
    define("DB_DATABASE", "");
    //checking if the connection is made succesful or not 
    if(!$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE)){
        die("failed to connect");
    }
```

Comment: It's `random_int` not `random_num` and it takes 2 arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of issues going on here. The first is formatting, watch your spacing/indenting/etc. I had to paste it out and reformat it to easily read what was going on. Your future self (and other devs) will thank you!

Once it was cleaned up slightly, it made it easier to see what's going on. You've got a few issues, one of which is

#### INSERTING USER DATA DIRECTLY INTO THE DATABASE

This may be because you're working on learning (we've all been there!), but never ever *ever* drop user supplied data into the database without validating and sanitizing it first, lest you open yourself up to SQL Injection Attacks. You'll want to look through [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) ASAP.

Also in your first block of code `header(Location:login.php);` should be `header('Location: login.php');` (also try and use fully realized URLs instead of relative paths, as those are reliant on the current file's location.

There's a couple other minor things, but the last issue before your main issue is that your `random_num()` function has a typo in it, `$len = ran(4,$length);`, `ran()` is not a function. If it were running, you'd get **another** undefined function error. (side note, consider using `mt_rand()` instead of `rand()`)

> Also, why are you generating random numbers as user ID's? There are going to be collisions at some point. You should be using an AUTO_INCREMENT integer field in your database for a user ID. If you want "big numbers" for some reason, you can always display them as a different base, encrypt them, etc. But you should start at user ID 1, and let the Auto Increment take care of the rest.

---

Whew! With all that out of the way, it looks like your `functions.php` file isn't being included (otherwise, you'd be getting that `ran()` is an undefined function error.

When including "core" files like this, you should be using `require_once` instead of `include`. The difference being that `require` will error-out the site if the file isn't found. You likely have it in the wrong location or it's named wrong `function.php`/`functions.php`, etc. Another benefit of using `require_once` is that if you ever add a second file, and `include` the functions again, you'll get "already defined" function errors, where using `require_once` will avoid loading files a second time if they're already found.

I won't bother you with autoloading (but you may want to look into it). But making sure that you've fixed the `header()` and `ran()` errors, and making sure that you've got the right file name **and** location, using `require_once` should get you up and running.

---

Also, I stress again, don't drop user supplied input directly into the database without validation/sanitization!

Comment: This was useful i was able to solve the typo erros I have and also solved the spaces and the indexing error . now my signup form is working pretty normal but I am not able to enter the values in the database . m

Answer (score 0):

Define the random_num() function or use rand() or random_int().

Comment: where i should define it ?

Comment: In a separate file and include it, or on the page like you do with check_login().

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare random_int() in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\functions.php on line 30 now giving me this error

Comment: I told you to define `random_num()` or use (as in replace) the call to `random_num()` with a call to `random_int()` instead.

Comment: can you change in my code and then post please I am new to php and not getting it

Comment: You will figure it out.  Keep going.

Comment: @AllanWind there is a `function random_num($length){` just after the check_login function

Comment: Yeah... I wonder if the file is just not being included then?